# Inflate data to FlatList from a variable React-Native

Tags: javascript, json, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am storing a JSON file in the local storage using react-native-fs
and fetching the data from the JSON file and storing it in a variable.

I want to fetch the data stored in the variable  and inflate it on a FlatList.

I have tried

```
// getting data from the local file
var path = RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath + '/test.json';
return RNFS.readFile(path, 'utf8')
  .then((success) => {
      console.log(success);//Data is storing successfully see console output below
      this.setState({        
      isLoading: false,
      dataSource: success.recordset //data is not getting separated with respect to recordset 
    });
    console.log(dataSource);//see outpout below
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err.message);
  });
```

console.log(success) output

> [{"recordset":[[{"id":1,"UPRN":552,"SiteName":"County         Hall","DueDate":"2019-04-26T00:00:00.000Z","SurveyStatus":"Completed","SyncStatus":"Completed"},{"id":2,"UPRN":554,"SiteName":"County Hall 2","DueDate":"2019-03-01T00:00:00.000Z","SurveyStatus":"Completed","SyncStatus":"sync-in-progress"},{"id":3,"UPRN":1524,"SiteName":"County Hall 3","DueDate":"2019-03-02T00:00:00.000Z","SurveyStatus":"Survey-in-progress","SyncStatus":null},{"id":4,"UPRN":2546,"SiteName":"County Hall 4","DueDate":"2019-03-15T00:00:00.000Z","SurveyStatus":null,"SyncStatus":null},{"id":5,"UPRN":2156,"SiteName":"County Hall 5","DueDate":"2019-07-01T00:00:00.000Z","SurveyStatus":null,"SyncStatus":null},{"id":6,"UPRN":8945,"SiteName":"County Hall 6","DueDate":"2019-06-01T00:00:00.000Z","SurveyStatus":null,"SyncStatus":null},{"id":7,"UPRN":5214,"SiteName":"County Hall 7","DueDate":"2020-06-01T00:00:00.000Z","SurveyStatus":null,"SyncStatus":null}]]

console.log(dataSource) output

> dataSource is not defined

Flatlist code

```
    <FlatList
      data={this.state.dataSource}
      renderItem={({item}) =>
      <View style={styles.flatview}>
        <Text style={styles.name}>{item.UPRN}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.email}>{item.SiteName}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.email}>{item.DueDate}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.email}>{item.SurveyStatus}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.email}>{item.SyncStatus}</Text>
      </View>
      }
      keyExtractor={item => item.id}
    />
```

How do I inflate this data in FlatList with respect to id?

Comment: Well, It looks like your recordSet is inside an array, an the data is also in an array inside another array in recordSet. So, you should write `dataSource: success[0].recordset[0]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few things going on here.

First, your `dataSource is not defined` message is because the console.log statement is outside the scope of the `RNFS.readFile` result.

Second you need to parse the JSON to convert the contents of the json file to objects, for example:

```
JSON.parse(success).then(result => this.setState({dataSource, result[0].recordset})
```

Third it looks like `recordset` is in an array which is why it's referenced above as `result[0].recordset`.

Comment: the idea to parse the 'success' was correct. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just do it like

```js
var path = RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath + '/test.json';
return RNFS.readFile(path, 'utf8')
  .then((success) => {
      console.log(success);//Data is storing successfully see console output below

   const dataSource = success[0].recordset[0]

 this.setState({        
      isLoading: false,
      dataSource
    });
    console.log(dataSource);//see outpout below
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err.message);
  });
```

the error is because you are using the datasource and it is undefined . you need to define the variable you are using.

and try to format your json array to

```
{"recordset":[{"id":1,"UPRN":552,"SiteName":"County Hall","DueDate":"2019-04-26T00:00:00.000Z","SurveyStatus":"Completed","SyncStatus":"Completed"},{"id":2,"UPRN":554,"SiteName":"County Hall 2","DueDate":"2019-03-01T00:00:00.000Z","SurveyStatus":"Completed","SyncStatus":"sync-in-progress"},{"id":3,"UPRN":1524,"SiteName":"County Hall 3","DueDate":"2019-03-02T00:00:00.000Z","SurveyStatus":"Survey-in-progress","SyncStatus":null},{"id":4,"UPRN":2546,"SiteName":"County Hall 4","DueDate":"2019-03-15T00:00:00.000Z","SurveyStatus":null,"SyncStatus":null},{"id":5,"UPRN":2156,"SiteName":"County Hall 5","DueDate":"2019-07-01T00:00:00.000Z","SurveyStatus":null,"SyncStatus":null},{"id":6,"UPRN":8945,"SiteName":"County Hall 6","DueDate":"2019-06-01T00:00:00.000Z","SurveyStatus":null,"SyncStatus":null},{"id":7,"UPRN":5214,"SiteName":"County Hall 7","DueDate":"2020-06-01T00:00:00.000Z","SurveyStatus":null,"SyncStatus":null}]}
```

because you are accessing the wrong variable